# Javascript Selenium Webdriver with Edge TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of null

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, typeerror

I'm trying to set up selenium-webdriver example using Javascript and Microsoft Edge. In any other browser this code below works. But Edge won't start. I tried to find a solution, but couldnt find anything that helped me... Maybe you can help.

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge').build();
  try {
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

Its to easiest example from the webdriver's npm-page. https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver

I'm getting following error:

```
[Running] node "c:\Users\mr\Desktop\Selenium\SeleniumToJS\test.js"
(node:3700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of null
(node:3700) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.512 seconds
```

If I insert 'edge' instead of 'MicrosoftEdge' follwing returns:

```
[Running] node "c:\Users\mreinwald\Desktop\Selenium\SeleniumToJS\loginLogout.js"
(node:18112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Do not know how to build driver: edge; did you forget to call usingServer(url)?
(node:18112) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.499 seconds
```

Comment: why `'MicrosoftEdge'` and not `'edge'`? Also, is the edge webdriver in the `PATH`?

Comment: I first tried 'edge' but this didnt work either. Yeah the edge webdriver is in PATH defined.

Comment: With `'edge'` is the same error?

Comment: Its the same type of error but an different error.
`(node:18112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Do not know how to build driver: edge; did you forget to call usingServer(url)?`
How do I use `usingServer(url)`?

Comment: Do you have latest selenium?

Comment: Yes, its the newest version.I installed it via `npm install selenium-webdriver`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line triggers the error:

`new Builder().forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge').build();`

`Cannot read property 'start' of null` actually says: *"I don't know what MicrosoftEdge is"*. Basically, in some instances, selenium expects one of: `"firefox"`, `"edge"` (instead of `"MicrosoftEdge"`), `"chrome"`, etc

Now

### The main topic:

`Do not know how to build driver: edge; did you forget to call usingServer(url)?`

This can happen due to many reasons:

1. Is edge installed?
2. Do you have the latest [MicrosoftEdgeDriver](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687) server.?
3. Is `MicrosoftEdgeDriver` is on your [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)?

If you answer yes to all of the above, then behind the scenes, while building, selenium didn't get the expected capabilities, and, for a last attempt, tries to connect to a remote `webDriver` (that's why it says `usingServer`)

As such, to solve this, you can try building the driver yourself, like this:

```
var edge = require('selenium-webdriver/edge');

var service = new edge.ServiceBuilder()
    .setPort(55555)
    .build();

var options = new edge.Options();
// configure browser options ...

var driver = edge.Driver.createSession(options, service);
```

And then you can continue with `driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is: **webdriver is looking for Edge Service to start while creating edge session and it find it to null(as its not set).**

The simple solution is create Edge service using Edge drive path.

```
    const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
    const edge = require('selenium-webdriver/edge');
    const edgedriver = require('edgedriver');   //If this driver is already on your system, then no need to install using npm.

    (async function example() {
        let service = await new edge.ServiceBuilder(edgedriver.path);
        let driver = await new Builder.forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge').setEdgeService(service).build();

        try {
            await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
            //...............
            //...............
        } finally {
            await driver.quit();
        }
    })();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by importing "Browser" from selenium-webdriver:

```
const { Browser } = require("selenium-webdriver");
```

And then creating the edge driver with:

```
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.EDGE).build();
```