# How to work with Edge browser using Selenium webdriver-js

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to Launch edge using selenium-webdriver-js ( javascript, not Java). i am facing issues in launching the edge browser, all other browsers work fine for me.

```
var wd = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new wd.Builder().forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge').build();
    driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
    driver.quit();
```

I am  getting the following error.

```
WebDriverError: Unknown error
    at parseHttpResponse (D:\selenium-js\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:536:11)
    at doSend.then.response (D:\selenium-js\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (D:\selenium-js\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (D:\selenium-js\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\edge.js:281:41)
    at createDriver (D:\selenium-js\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (D:\selenium-js\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:651:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\selenium-js\sampleScripts\yourProduct\features\stepdefinition\DifferentBrowser.js:23:59)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Can you help me in getting the solution or working code? I don't know what i am missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Selenium Webdriver with Edge TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577924/javascript-selenium-webdriver-with-edge-typeerror-cannot-read-property-start)

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure to PATH to MicrosoftWebDriver.msi should be valid and your webdriver should support your browser's version.

Your code doesn't contain setup to access to selenium server and webdriver. If selenium server isn't defined, It connects to "localhost:4444" by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { Builder, By, Key } = require("selenium-webdriver");

async function example() {
    const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("MicrosoftEdge").build();
    const URL = "https://www.google.com/";
    driver.get(URL);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}

example();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can download the edge webdriver fromhttps://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
Then you can unzip it and copy the msedgedriver.exe file into your project root
or you can configure it in environment variables.
This should be fine